# Multi-threading with Sequel gem

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sequel

I have a program that is storing JSON request data into a Postgres DB using the Sequel gem (it's basically a price aggregator). However, the data is being pulled from multiple locations rapidly using threads.

Once I get the appropriate data, I currently have a mutex.synchronize with the following:

```
dbItem = Item.where(:sku => sku).first
dbItem = Item.create(:sku => sku, :name => itemName) if dbItem == nil
dbPrice = Price.create(:price => foundPrice, :quantity => quantity)
dbItem.add_price(dbPrice)
store.add_price(dbPrice)
```

If I run this without a mutex, I get threading issues - for example, the code will try to create an item in the DB, but the item will have just been created by another thread.

However, with the mutex, this code gets slowed down significantly - I'm seeing my program take ~four-six times longer.

I'm new to the whole database thing honestly, so I'm just trying to figure out the best way to handle threading. Am I doing this wrong? The documentation for Sequel actually states that almost everything threadsafe... *except* for model instances, which I believe my item situation falls under. It states I should freeze models first, but I don't know how to apply that here..

Comment: I don't have your answer, but, one of the things that put ruby on the map was rails & activerecord. I feel like activerecord might better solve your threading issue, and it has enough use that it's performance is probably pretty good. Once you get it's ORM down, it is quite fun to use.
(http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html)

Answer (score 2):

You aren't dealing with shared model instances, and this isn't a thread-safety issue, it is a race condition (it would happen using multiple processes, not just multiple threads).  You need to use database-specific support to handle this in a race-condition free way.  On PostgreSQL 9.5+, you would need to use Dataset#insert_conflict.

Sequel documentation: http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc-adapters/classes/Sequel/Postgres/DatasetMethods.html#method-i-insert_conflict

PostgreSQL documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-insert.html

Comment: Ah, very interesting. That makes much more sense. And in the case of updating an entry that another thread might be updating at the same time, that is automatically thread safe or no? Is that a case where I'm supposed to freeze the entry?

Comment: As I mentioned, this isn't a thread-safety issue, so freezing anything wouldn't help.  The issue is a race condition in terms of accessing the database, so you have to use a database-specific method for handling this.  It's often called upsert, since what it does is: insert, if unique constraint violation, then update existing row.